# PostgreSQL Trigger apos update

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Vamos imaginar o seguinde cenário:

```
CREATE TABLE invalido (
   ds_valor character varying(255)
)

CREATE TABLE email (
    email character varying(255)
)
```

agora preciso de uma `trigger` que toda vez que eu execute um `UPDATE` ou `INSERT` na tabela `email` ele verifique se o valor está na tabela  `invalido`, se estiver então deve substituir o que seria inserido na tabela `email` por **email invalido**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, crie uma função que retorna o tipo `trigger`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION validar_email()
RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT
               FROM invalido
              WHERE ds_valor = NEW.email) THEN
    NEW.email := ''email invalido'';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Depois crie um `trigger` que dispara antes do `INSERT` e do `UPDATE` que irá permitir que o valor seja alterado e execute a função acima:

**edit:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_before_iu_email
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON email
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE validar_email()
```

Comment: syntax error at or near "UPDATE", removendo o UPDATE roda...

Comment: tenta colocar BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE e me confirma se deu certo, por favor

Comment: Aprovae então ^^

Comment: @Sorack Eu sei que esse post é um pouco antigo mas eu consigo aplicar essa ideia se eu tiver o seguinte cenário, possuo uma tabela 01 com colunas id_cliente e nome_cliente e a tabela 02 também com colunas id_cliente e nome_cliente, eu preciso que se eu alterar o registro da coluna nome_cliente na tabela 01 o registro que tiver o mesmo id_cliente na tabela 02 altere o registro nome_cliente também, é possível?

Comment: @R.Santos boa pergunta. Teria que dar uma pesquisada pra ver se você pode fazer alteração em outra tabela com `trigger` no `Postgres`. Mas você pode abrir uma pergunta e a gente dá uma olhada

Comment: Eu abri uma assim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204026/trigger-que-atualize-registro-em-uma-tabela se por acaso tu achar alguma ideia eu te agradeço, não precisa ser necessariamente via trigger, se tu tiver qualquer ideia que eu possa fazer isso já é um caminho :)

Answer (score 1):

Olá... @Sorack sim dá para fazer... sim...

somente coloque um Update dentro da trigger ex:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_before_update_c0220 ( ) 

RETURNS trigger AS $body$ begin

    if new.nome_cliente  <> old.nome_cliente then

       update public.table_02
          set nome_cliente  = new.nome_cliente 
        where id_cliente = new.id_cliente;
           end if;

    return new;      

end; 
$body$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 

VOLATILE CALLED ON NULL 

INPUT SECURITY INVOKER COST 100;
```