# SQLServer Trigger apos update

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Vamos imaginar o seguinde cenário:

```
CREATE TABLE invalido (
   ds_valor character varying(255)
)

CREATE TABLE email (
    email character varying(255)
)
```

agora preciso de uma `trigger` que toda vez que eu execute um `UPDATE` ou `INSERT` na tabela `email` ele verifique se o valor está na tabela  `invalido`, se estiver então deve substituir o que seria inserido na tabela `email` por **email invalido**.

Mesma situação da: [PostgreSQL Trigger apos update](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164179/postgresql-trigger-apos-update) porem com SQLServer

Comment: David, você pode adicionar a pergunta o que tentou até agora?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basicamente, é isso aqui

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].AfterUpdateOrInsertEmail 
ON [dbo].email

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].invalido inv WHERE inv.ds_valor = (Select Inserted.Email From Inserted))
    BEGIN
        Update Email Set email = 'inválido' From Inserted;
    END
END
```

Comment: Entrou em looping :(

Comment: Ora, mas a estrutura é exatamente essa da pergunta? Eu repliquei a estrutura aqui e funciona normal.

Comment: Vou ver se tem alguma outra trigger que possa ter bugado...

Comment: Update Email Set email = 'inválido' From Inserted; isso não precisa de where? coloquei o where e funcionou

Answer (score 1):

O ideal para que a estrutura funcionasse da melhor forma era que sua tabela `email` tivesse um `id` único, assim seria possível fazer com uma `trigger instead of` que faria o tratamento antes mesmo de do `insert` ou `update`.

Você pode criar uma `trigger` com `inner join` na tabela `invalido`, garantindo que apenas os registros inválidos serão alterados.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_after_iu_email ON email AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  set nocount on;

  UPDATE ema
     SET ema.email = 'email invalido'
    FROM email ema
         INNER JOIN inserted ins on ins.email = ema.email
         INNER JOIN invalido inv on inv.ds_valor = ins.email;
END;
GO
```

**Observação:** Caso exista um registro na tabela `invalido` com o valor `email invalido` a `trigger` entrará em `looping` infinito.