# Trigger que atualize registro em uma tabela

Tags: postgresql, trigger, pgadmin

Preciso atualizar uma tabela X sempre que na tabela Y houver alguma alteração. Encontrei inúmeros exemplos de como salvar os registros alterados na tabela Y, tanto quando é deletado um registro da tabela X quanto quando for alterado ou inserido, mas minha necessidade não é criar uma linha nova na tabela Y sempre que um registro for alterado na tabela X, eu preciso apenas alterar a linha que possui o mesmo código e que teve a informação alterada.

Exemplo:

Possuo duas tabelas, onde existem duas colunas, id_cliente e nome_cliente, o que preciso é que quando o nome do cliente for alterado na tabela 01, automaticamente seja alterado o nome do cliente na tabela 02 que tenha o mesmo id.

Encontrei como adicionar uma linha nova com o seguinte comando:

```
create or replace function salvaexcluido()
returns trigger as
$BODY$ begin
insert into bk_transportadora values (old.codigo, old.nome, old.status);

return null;
end;$BODY$
language 'plpgsql'
```

Nesse caso seria adicionado uma nova linha sempre que fosse excluído algum registro. Se tiverem alguma ideia seria ótimo mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar `insert`, utilize o `update`:

```
UPDATE bk_transportadora 
   SET nome = new.nome
 WHERE id = new.id;
```

Agora uma informação relevante que não é uma resposta a sua pergunta: Talvez a melhor forma de resolver o seu problema não seja atualizando a outra tabela com uma `trigger`, e sim utilizando um `JOIN` ou uma `SUBQUERY` para obter a informação da tabela atualizada. Assim você evita redundância no banco de dados e garante que a informação estará igual em todos os lugares.

Answer (score 1):

Minha *Funtion()* no fim ficou assim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.atualiza_transportadora()
RETURNS trigger
AS
$$
begin

IF NEW.nome <> OLD.nome \\ Aqui eu verifico se houve a alteração do nome
THEN
UPDATE bk_transportadora
SET transportadora = new.nome
where codigo = old.codigo; \\ Aqui atualizo a informação da outra tabela apenas se o código é igual

END IF;
return null;
end
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Depois tive que aciona-la com a trigger apenas:

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualizar_transportadora AFTER UPDATE
ON transportadora FOR EACH ROW  
EXECUTE PROCEDURE atualiza_transportadora();
```